# Building pyspotify in 32bit Python OSX Mavericks

Tags: python

I'm trying to build `pyspotify`, but after installation and `>>import spotify`, I get:

```
import _cffi_backend as backend
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_cffi_backend.so, 2):             no suitable image found.  Did find:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_cffi_backend.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

my `uname -p` gets `i386`, and I guess `pyspotify` it is not prebuilt for this architecture.

documentations says:

In that case, you’ll need a C compiler, Python development headers, and libffi development headers to build pyspotify

how do I do that?

Comment: try using [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and install gcc, libffi and python (I think that should grab the development headers)

Comment: hey @Jeff Tratner, I did what you suggested, but still get the same `mach-o, but wrong architecture` message when importing spotify into python...does this `brew python` does not conflict with my system python? my `brew list` already had python, as well as `libffi`. I only installed `gcc`. thanks